# Record chatter post with link

Tags: apex, connect-api

Using ConnectApi
Reference: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectAPI_outputs.htm#capi_entityLinkSeg_output

I want to  create from apex code a chatter post on a record, a post that will include a link to a site
[image]

exactly i want to create ,from apex,the following:
[image]

Do you know if there is some function to accomplish that?

Thanks in advantage for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of Mohith i got the solution:
Usign ConnectApi.LinkSegmentinput isn´t giving the desired solution:
Code(working with test account hardcoded):

```
    ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
    messageInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();


    ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
    textSegment.text = 'text ';
    messageInput.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

    ConnectApi.LinkSegmentinput linksegment = new ConnectApi.LinkSegmentinput();
            linksegment.url = 'http://testme.com';
   messageInput.messageSegments.add(linksegment);



    ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
    input.body = messageInput;
       ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, '001g000000FrBWt', input, null);
```

this is the result:
[image]

The desidered solution for me is usign ConnectApi.LinkAttachmentInput:

```
ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
    feedItemInput.body = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();

    // add the text segment
    ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
    feedItemInput.body.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();
    textSegment.text = 'postText';
    feedItemInput.body.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

    // add the attachment
    ConnectApi.LinkAttachmentInput linkIn = new ConnectApi.LinkAttachmentInput();
    linkIn.urlName = 'urlName';
    linkIn.url = 'url';
    feedItemInput.attachment = linkIn;


       ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, '001g000000FrBWt',feedItemInput, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Adding a Link post

FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = oId; //eg. Opportunity id, custom object id..
post.Body = 'Enter post text here';
post.LinkUrl = 'http://www.someurl.com';
insert post;
```

If you are not using community,the following should work using simple apex .

Other way to use will be using connect API

```
  ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input=new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
  ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput  body1 = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();  
body1.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();
ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textSegment.text ='message';
body1.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

 // linksegment
    ConnectApi.LinkSegmentInput linksegment = new ConnectApi.LinkSegmentInput();
    linksegment.url = 'http://testme.com';
    body1.messageSegments.add(linksegment);
    input.body=body1 ;

  ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(Network.getNetworkId(),ConnectApi.FeedType.News,'me',input,null);
```

Comment: Thanks Mohith, i need to do it with Connect Api. Do you know if is it feasible?

Comment: Ok hold on ..its feasible ..I am updating the answer

Comment: Added the code .Let me know if issues

Comment: Thanks again. i get a compiler error about : Incompatible element type ConnectApi.LinkSegment segmentList.add(linksegment); for collection of ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput.

Comment: no luck :( 
Save error: Illegal assignment from LIST<ConnectApi.MessageSegment> to ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput

Comment: ok i will get back once i am out of a meeting .Some simple data assignment issues

Comment: Ok i have added proper code .Please test and accept as may help lot of people

Comment: i got the solution Mohith, i ve just added the description. Posted code is working and tested. Thanks :)

Comment: looks like both of us at same time got the solution