# How can I use ConnectApi.LinkCapabilityInput to create Chatter posts from Apex?

Tags: apex, chatter, chatter-api

I need to use Apex to create a chatter post on an Account object, which will include some text which is a clickable hyperlink.  After hours of confusing searches, I thought I had found the solution [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32511/record-chatter-post-with-link), which looks like it does what I need using LinkAttachmentInput but when I tried it out I discovered:

*ConnectApi.LinkAttachmentInput
    This class isn’t available in version 32.0 and later. In version 32.0 and later, use the ConnectApi.LinkCapabilityInput class.*

Unfortunately, after more hours of searching online, I can't find any examples of how to use this new "capabilities" scheme.  Has anyone managed to figure out how to use it to embed a link in a post to be created by calling ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement() ?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_input_link_capability.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some sample code, which I adapted from an [example for posting files](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_content.htm):

```
// Define the FeedItemInput object to pass to postFeedElement
ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
feedItemInput.subjectId = 'me';

ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textSegmentInput.text = 'Check out this link.';

// The MessageBodyInput object holds the text in the post
ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);
feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;

// The FeedElementCapabilitiesInput object holds the capabilities of the feed item.
// For this feed item, we define a link capability.

ConnectApi.LinkCapabilityInput linkInput = new ConnectApi.LinkCapabilityInput();
linkInput.url = 'https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_input_link_capability.htm';
linkInput.urlName = 'Doc link';

ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput feedElementCapabilitiesInput = new ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput();
feedElementCapabilitiesInput.link = linkInput;

feedItemInput.capabilities = feedElementCapabilitiesInput;

// Post the feed item. 
ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), feedItemInput);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this example; it helped me a lot.  I was able to get my link to show up within the chatter post, so I'm marking this as the correct answer.   Clicking the link opens the url in a new browser tab or window.  (I wish Salesforce would provide the capability to open the link in the same window,  but I guess that's another topic.)